# Cannot use postgresql on Ubuntu terminal, getting errors

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

---

`psql` is successfully installed on my Linux environment (Ubuntu) but when using `psql` commands I get the following

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried the previous solutions but none of thrm are working. Server status is also not shown, and logfile is empty, and some commands ask for a password that I never set.

Output for `dkpg -l | grep postgres`

```
ii  postgresql                     12+214                            all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-12                  12.2-4                            amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 12 server
ii  postgresql-client-12           12.2-4                            amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 12
ii  postgresql-client-common       214                               all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common              214                               all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib             12+214                            all          additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)
```

Comment: Is postgres running ie ie what is the state of postgresql@11-main ? (if systemd on debian 10)  /run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 is the local unix socket for one instance of postgres postmaster.

Comment: It seems that the postgres server is not running. Can you run `dpkg -l | grep postgres` and add its output to the original question?